# Use of Dual Schottky diode in voltage supervisor output

Tags: schottky

I was exploring one of the popular Tiva C launchpad (http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Tiva_C_Series_LaunchPads) to create a custom board based on TM4C123GXL evaluation kit.

There is a Schottky diode connected to the RESET output of the voltage supervisor in the schematic as shown below

[image]

One of the anodes goes to the RESET pin of the main microcontroller and the other one to the RESET pin of another microcontroller which act as an inbuilt debugger/programmer.

What is the use of a Schottky diode in the output of a voltage supervisor like this?

Note : +VBUS is the +5V coming from USB connector

Comment: The diodes are placed so –TARGETRST and –ICDI_RST can't influence each other.

Comment: It's sometimes called a "diode-or." However, the polarity of the diodes looks a little odd to me.

Comment: I have just had to deal with an ST microcontroller that holds its own `RST` pin low during start-up. We have to do something similar to protect other devices on the shared `RST` line from being affected

Answer (score 1):

The voltage supervisor can pull both TARGETRST and ICDI_RST low but TARGETRST cannot pull ICDI_RST low or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing (the diodes look backwards) because you can't see where the other lines go- to two RC circuits with pullups.

[image]

[image]

The supervisor chip pulls both resets (active) low, but the RESET pushbutton does not affect ICDI_RST.

Comment: According to the polarity of the Schottky diode shown in the pic, the 10K pull-up resistor on voltage supervisor output seems useless. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you're basically right, with 10K resistors even at high Ta leakage isn't all that significant.